# A nontechnical way to comprehend $\aleph_2$

Tags: soft-question, cardinals

This is possibly a dumb question, but I do not know where to look for an answer.

Without getting technical, one can show why $card(\mathbb{N}) = card(\mathbb{Q}).$ (Typically by showing how the two sets are countable and by showing a one-to-one correspondence between them. In the same manner, we see why the set of real numbers is uncountable and why there cannot be a one-to-one correspondence between the set of natural numbers and the set of real numbers. Again, *without getting technical, say, without the concept of power set and all that,* is it possible to show why $\aleph_1 < \aleph_2?$ Why there cannot be a one-to-one correspondence between them?

Another potentially dumb question: If the set of natural numbers is countable, and the set of real numbers is uncountable, what feature does the set of $2^{\aleph_1}$ possess that the set of real numbers do not? Is that even a meaningful question?

Comment: @GFauxPas $\aleph_2$ **isn't** defined in terms of powersets in the first place . . .

Comment: @Noah I was confusing $\beth_n$ with $\aleph_n$, sorry.

Comment: $\aleph_1\lt\aleph_2$ is true by definition, since $\aleph_2$ is **defined** as the smallest cardinal which is greater than $\aleph_1.$ More precisely, it's the cardinality of a well-ordered set which has cardinality greater than $\aleph_1$ while every proper initial segment has cardinality less than or equal to $\aleph_1.$

Comment: I'd hesitate to call *any* question about cardinals a dumb question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me tackle your second question first, since it's easier. The following is *consistent with ZFC* (that is, the usual axioms of set theory can neither prove nor disprove the following): $$2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$ So even though $\aleph_1>\aleph_0$ by definition (see below for more on this), it's possible their power sets have the same size!

Re: your first question, let's begin by recalling the definition of the $\aleph$s:

> An **initial ordinal** is an ordinal which is not in bijection with any smaller ordinal. For an ordinal $\alpha$, $\omega_\alpha$ is the unique ordinal $\theta$ such that $\{\beta<\theta: \beta\mbox{ is an initial ordinal}\}$ has order-type $\alpha$.

Initial ordinals are also called **cardinals** - that is, $\aleph_\alpha$ is just another notation for $\omega_\alpha$. (This is a bit sloppy - I'm ignoring some nuance in the notations - but it will serve.)

So *by definition* we have $\aleph_1<\aleph_2$.

However, you're presumably interested in *examples* of sets with cardinality $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$ respectively. This gets nastier. The good news is that there are such examples: the set of countable ordinals is a set of size $\aleph_1$ (in fact, it **is** the ordinal $\omega_1$), and the set of ordinals of cardinality at most $\aleph_1$ is a set of size $\aleph_2$ (in fact, it **is** the ordinal $\omega_2$).

The bad news is that if you want examples that *aren't built from ordinals*, you're basically out of luck; for example, it is consistent that the set of real numbers has cardinality $\aleph_{17}$ or has cardinality $\aleph_1$, so we can't even say whether $\aleph_2$ is the cardinality of some set of reals!

Even for $\aleph_1$ - which we *know* is the cardinality of some set of reals - the situation is very murky. It is consistent with ZFC that there is no "easily definable" set of reals of cardinality exactly $\aleph_1$; and similar results hold for $\aleph_2$ under the appropriate nontriviality assumption $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_2$. Look up **descriptive set theory** for more detail.

---

**Tl;dr**: The clearest description of higher $\aleph$s you'll get is in terms of sets of ordinals, and the universe of $\aleph$s is built up inductively; any other type of representation (e.g. as sets of reals, etc.) will generally not be possible (or at least it will be consistent that no such representation exists).

Comment: I'll make a complete fool of myself with a third question then: What insight do we gain by studying higher cardinals? Which fields of mathematics further develop (apart from the field which studies them) by the results obtained from the mathematics of cardinals?

Comment: Not a foolish question at all! However, it is really broad, and I have to go eat dinner, so for now let me just admit that set theory is definitely more "out there" than, say, topology, but also does have applications to other areas of mathematics, and drop some links: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182033/the-impact-of-large-cardinals-in-mathematics, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129575/does-an-existence-of-large-cardinals-have-implications-in-number-theory-or-combi, and Ashutosh's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142108/proving-zfc-results-using-large-cardinals.